# ASP .NET Identity - How To Validate Auth Token In Custom Filter Attribute

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a question about verifying an Auth Token.  Currently, I'm generating my Auth Token at `/token` and sending it back to the client side where I store it in session storage.  To make the process as secure as possible I'm looking to store the token in a `HttpOnly` and `Secure` cookie to protect against XSS.

I'm sending the cookie along with a `XSRF` token where on my client side (Angular) I set the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header to the `XSRF`  token value.  The browser then automatically send the Auth Cookie back to me where I can read the token.

**My main question is how do I extract the token and validate it?** Before I was using Authentication Bear `auth_token` with the `[Authorize]` attribute but that doesn't work now since the token is in a cookie.  I made my own Attribute (see below, but I'm stuck on the line where I actually verify the token.  I'm not sure what function to call and pass the token to, to validate it.

```
public class ValidateToken : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
            CookieHeaderValue authToken = headers.GetCookies().FirstOrDefault();

            CookieState authCookie = authToken.Cookies.Where(p => p.Name == "AUTH-TOKEN").FirstOrDefault();
            if (authCookie.Value is valid -> need help here) {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I've tried the following

```
actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authCookie.Value);
bool isAuth = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
```

But the `RequestContext` is already set once `OnAuthorization` is called and it doesn't update to use the new Header I added.

Comment: The `[Authorize]` attribute works in this case. It means you have the Authentication setup messed up.

Comment: @HubertJarema What do you mean `[Authorize]` works in this case? Since I'm sending the token in a cookie and not setting the Authorization: Bearer... client side, I can't use `[Authorize]` since it doesn't know about the cookie.  I need my own `AuthorizeAttribute` to read the cookie and set the header, but from there is seems the identity is already null and it doesn't take into the fact I changed the Authorization header in `OnAuthorization`

Comment: Inside my `Application_BeginRequest()` I check for the cookie and set the `Authorization` header if the value exists.  I'm using the standard `[Authorize]` attribute and it seems to be working fine

Comment: @DevEng - 99.999999% of the time when someone says "I need my own `[Authorize]` attribute", it's because they don't really understand what they're doing.  The Authorize attribute should not be reading cookie values, nor should it be setting headers.  It's only job is to read data that is already present in the context and decide if it should approve access.  All your cookie and header code should take place early in the lifecycle, and set the appropriate data in the context for the Authorize attribute to read.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch ya, I've gone ahead and set the `Authorization` header earlier in the pipeline and kept the `[Authorize`], it's fine now.